# How to execute shell command from php in background

Tags: php, shell, exec

How can I execute shell command in background using `&` at the end? I've try:

```
php -r "shell_exec('sleep 10 &');"
```

and

```
php -r "shell_exec('/bin/bash -c \"sleep 10 &\"');"
```

in both cases it pause for 10 seconds instead of just give the shell back and run sleep in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reroute the output somewhere. Try something like this:

```
php -r "shell_exec('sleep 10 > /dev/null &');"
```